# Работа со списком по условию

Tags: python, список

У меня есть список с рандомными цифрами от 0 до 500.

```
lst = [123,255,51,0,9,18]
```

Я работаю с этими числами, ставя много условий

```
for i in lst:
    if 120 < i < 125:
        func1()
    if 0 <= i <= 20:
        func2()...
```

Вопрос вот в чем: у меня много заданных неравенств для i, их около 50. Для каждого условия с этими неравенствами написана своя функция, не суть.

Мне теперь нужно написать последнее условие для всех чисел от 0 до 500, не попадающих под вышенаписанные неравенства. Вручную отбирать все непопавшие числа не вариант.

Нужно что-то вроде:

```
 for n in lst:
     if n != i: (всем вышенаписанным i)
         continue
```

Как отобрать все i, которые не вошли в мои условия?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте: `if` + `elif` (`else if`) + `else`:

```
for i in lst:
    if 120 < i < 125:
        func1()
    elif 0 <= i <= 20:
        func2()
    else:
        # Все остальные условия не прошли
        print(i)
```

---

Если реализовать как было предложено в вопросе, то выйдет как-то так (`if`+`elif`+`else` явно проще, имея тот же результат):

```
lst = [123,255,51,0,9,18]
other_lst = []

def func1(i):
    other_lst.append(i)
    # ...

def func2(i):
    other_lst.append(i)
    # ...

for i in lst:
    if 120 < i < 125:
        func1(i)
    if 0 <= i <= 20:
        func2(i)

    if i not in other_lst:
        print(i)
        continue
```

Консоль:

```
255
51
```

Answer (score 1):

вообще в похожих случаях для ускорения поиска можно было бы использовать две пайтоновские особенности:
 1. словарь (самая быстрая структура языка с точки зрения поиска по индексу)
 2. тот факт что все в пайтоне - объекты. То есть функции - тоже объекты первого уровня и их можна присваивать переменным.

Используя эти обстоятельства, можно упростить использование функций, если у них предполагается наличие параметров кроме `i`. Итак.

```
def dummy():           # function for 'other_i'
    print('another key')

switcher = dict.fromkeys(range(501), dummy)  # i.e. switcher = {i : dummy for i in range(501) }  -  all dict is 'dummy' function

def func_01()
    ....

def func_02()
    ....
...
def func_xx()
    ....


''' dictionary initialisation   '''
for i in range(501)
    if 120 < i < 125:
        switcher[i] = func_01
    elif 0 <= i <= 20:
        switcher[i] = func_02
    ...
    elif  0 <= i <= xx:
        switcher[i] = func_xx


lst = [123,255,51,0,9,18]
for i in lst:
    switcher[i]()
```

Такой подход оправдан при условии если действительно функций больно много.
Вся логика сосредотачивается в одном месте, а в основной программе просто вызывается по ключу нужная функция из словаря.